# UWP AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon disappears after Style added

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

When I added style to AutoSuggestBox Query Icon disappears. Any solutions?

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="AutoSuggestBoxStyle" TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
        <Setter Property="TextBoxStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Page Resources Style

```
<AutoSuggestBox
    x:Name="autoSuggestBox"
    Height="40"
    Margin="24,44,24,0"
    Text=""
    PlaceholderText="Wyszukaj serial..."
    QuerySubmitted="autoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
    SuggestionChosen="autoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen"
    TextChanged="autoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
    QueryIcon="Find"
    Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle}"/>
```

XML AutoSuggestBox

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a better way.

You can define another `TextBox` style which is based on the existing style `AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle`.

So you simply put the following into your resource dictionary.

```
<Style x:Key="BigAutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle" 
       TargetType="TextBox" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
</Style>
```

Then, just reference it on your `AutoSuggestBox`.

```
<AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find" 
                TextBoxStyle="{StaticResource BigAutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a solution:

[image: 1) First I edited template copy]

1) First I edited template copy, after PPM in design mode on AutoSuggestBox

[image]

2) Then I set FontSize in Resources.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Huh? It works perfectly on my end. When you create the full style, is the TextBox style called `AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle`?

Comment: Make sure you have `BasedOn="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle}"` there.